# EasyMock + Roboelectric + mocks for class

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, easymock, robolectric

I am trying to write some unittests for Android and I have following combination:

1) Roboectric (I want to run tests on JVM vs Dalvik)

2) EasyMock (I need to mock classes/interfaces)

3) I want to mock a class.

It works great if I use EasyMock 3.1. It wasn't Android aware, so it happily used cglib stuff and creates bytecode for JVM and create a mock for a class (the same way as it will do this for any non Android app).

However, if I switch to EasyMock 3.2 then it doesn work. It starts giving "ClassNotFoundException". And I feel like it's confused. On one hand, it sees that it's Android environment so probably it does something Android related. On other hand, because of Roboelectric, it runs on JVM (vs Dalvik).

Do you know how to turn off Android awareness in EasyMock 3.2 or higher to get rid of this issue?

Comment: Which class it can not find? Looking to https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/EASYMOCK-108 they added Android support to run test with easymock as part of instrumental tests. My suggestions: 1) silly - if you really don't need 3.2 stay on 3.1, 2) if you use maven or gradle - examine dependencies for easymock and try exlude "dexmaker", 3) another silly - use mockito

Comment: Please post it as the answer. It definitely deserve an upvote. #1 isn't silly (that's exactly what I am doing now). I tried #2 and it didn't help. #3 is possible, but it will be inconvenience for our team, because they use EasyMock on different projects.

Answer (score 1):

Looking to jira.codehaus.org/browse/EASYMOCK-108 they added Android support to run test with easymock as part of instrumental tests. 
My suggestions:

1. silly - if you really don't need 3.2 stay on 3.1
2. if you use maven or gradle - examine dependencies for easymock and try exlude "dexmaker"
3. another silly - use mockito